# NameError: in the file directory I'm trying to load a data for analysis

Tags: python, nameerror

I started to use Google Colab on Chrome on MacOSX and encountered the issue below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv(/Users/Shin/Box/PROJECTS/SOKENDAI/python_lesson/able_programing/titanic/'train.csv')
df.head
```

### Then I get the error below.  I am a beginner and not sure if the way I put file directory was wrong.  I've tried "c:Users""~Users", that did not work.
Thank you for your help.

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv(~Users/Shin/Box/PROJECTS/SOKENDAI/python_lesson/able_programing/titanic/'train.csv')
2 df.head

NameError: name 'Users' is not defined

Comment: Put the `'` before `train.csv` before `/Users/...` instead, the whole thing is the `str` (string) you want to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/Users/Shin/Box/PROJECTS/SOKENDAI/python_lesson/able_programing/titanic/train.csv` needs to be a string. Python has no way of telling if that's a file path or not.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/Shin/Box/PROJECTS/SOKENDAI/python_lesson/able_programing/titanic/train.csv')
df.head
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I tried what you suggested here, but no luck. Is it possible that I have to put the target file on Google Drive, as well?

Comment: @ShinSano I don't know. You probably should ask an another question for that. Could you also accept my answer? It gives you reputation and helps future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

There is a common trick in working with python's path.

- if you are building an application, which the users can be beyond yourself, the best way is to ask for input:

```py
file_path = input('Please input csv file path below: ')
```

in this way, python str class will automatically handle the slash conversion, which you don't have to deal with those stuff like `\`, `\\`, `/`, `//`. then in testing, what you need is copy the  **absolute path** and paste it in.

- another circumstance will be `py` file and `csv` are bundled in relevant directory, in this case use a relative path in following format:

```py
file_path = './train.csv'
```

I personally always uses the first method, although it's a little bit more to do, there is no potential bugs. in addition, to copy the abs path on MacOS, open a new terminal and drag the file into it, then you will be able to copy the path.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I'm working on the latter case but those files are not bundled in. So, I copied the absolute file path that I copied from the finder>get info., which did not work.  Is it possible that I have to put the target file on Google Drive, as well?